# "Type RootQueryType must define one or more fields." }

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

Trying to get GraphQL to work with JavaScript.  Not sure where my mistake is.

My code

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const _ = require('lodash');
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLSchema
} = graphql;
const users = [
  { id: "23", firstName: "Bill", age: 20},
  { id: "47", firstName: "Sam", age: 21}
];
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: {type: GraphQLString},
    firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
    age:{type: GraphQLInt}
  }
});
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
         return _.find(users, { id: args.id });
      }
    }
  }
});
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema ({
  query: RootQuery
});
```

I am getting

> {   "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Type RootQueryType must define one or more fields."
>       } 
>     ]  }

[image]

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to use an arrow function

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields:()=>( {
    id: {type: GraphQLString},
    firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
    age:{type: GraphQLInt}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mistake is simply in your Query.  You use the RootQueryType's `fields` object to make your query endpoints.  The `fields` object in your case only contains one query: `user`.  However you are trying to make a query for `User`, which is different.

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    // The items listed here are going to be your root query endpoints.
    // Which in this case is only `user`.
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLString } },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
         return _.find(users, { id: args.id });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

So you need to make your query using `user`.

Additionally, you need to make sure you are making your query correctly.  Basic query syntax for what you are trying to achieve looks like this:

```
{
  user(id: "23") {
    id
    firstName
    age
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

---

Some documentation on queries:

[GraphQL Queries](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/)

[DevHints - GraphQL](https://devhints.io/graphql)